# Laravel Excel: CSV to Array

Tags: php, arrays, excel, laravel, csv

So I am working on a form where I want o give the user the option of uploading a CSV that will allow the form to be automatically populated. So I thought I would build a function that reads the CSV and then throws each row into an array as an object which I can then pass back to my Laravel Blade template. My only problem is, the array I return from the function is always empty. Any ideas?

```
private function import($path) {
    $applicants = [];

    Excel::load($path, function(LaravelExcelReader $excel) use ($applicants){
        $excel->each(function(Collection $line) use ($applicants){      
            $name = new \stdClass;    

            $name->first = $line->get('first');
            $name->middle = $line->get('middle');
            $name->last = $line->get('last');
            $name->birthdate = $line->get('birthdate');
            $name->ssn = $line->get('ssn');
            $name->email = $line->get('email');
            $name->mobile_phone = $line->get('mobile_phone');
            $name->home_phone = $line->get('home_phone');
            $name->street = $line->get('street');
            $name->city = $line->get('city');
            $name->state = $line->get('state');
            $name->zip = $line->get('zip');

            array_push($applicants, $name);
        });
    });    

    return $applicants;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it by using `&` operator in the `use` statement as:

```
Excel::load($path, function(LaravelExcelReader $excel) use (&$applicants){
   ...
}
```

OR

Make `$applicants` a class property then use it in your function as:

```
private function import($path) {
    $this->applicants = [];

    Excel::load($path, function(LaravelExcelReader $excel) {
        $excel->each(function(Collection $line) {      
            ...

            array_push($this->applicants, $name);
        });
    });    

    return $this->applicants;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Install - https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

And then Try below code:

```
$reader = \Excel::load($file_path);                  //this will load file
$results = $reader->noHeading()->get()->toArray();   //this will convert file to array
foreach($results as $v){
    \\process your array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with using Laravel-Excel library for a very simple csv import, found a better solution using the [FastExcel](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel) library.

First, install it via composer: `composer require rap2hpoutre/fast-excel`

And then you can simply use a one liner:

```
$arrayName = (new \Rap2hpoutre\FastExcel\FastExcel)->import('folder/file.csv')->toArray();
```

Otherwise:

```
use Rap2hpoutre\FastExcel\FastExcel;

$arrayName = (new FastExcel)->import('folder/file.csv')->toArray();
```

It's a quick and easy way to load a csv!

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 6 && Maatwebsite Excel3   **Update:Jan 21 2020**

```
$data = Excel::toArray(new \App\Imports\BaseImport(), $request->file('csv_file'));
```

Base import file

```
namespace App\Imports;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

class BaseImport implements ToCollection {

    /**
     * @param Collection $collection
     */
    public function collection(Collection $rows) {
        return $rows;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
array_push($applicants, $name);
```

try this

```
$applicants[] = $name;
```

let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

A slight refinement to @mujuonly answer, using an anonymous class.

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

$array = Excel::toArray(new class implements ToCollection {
        public function collection(\Illuminate\Support\Collection $rows) {
            return $rows;
        }
    }, $csvFile
);
```